# Populate selection box based on query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form (queform plugin on wordpress) that I am trying to populate based on some table information.

Initially I had a shortcode plugged in which is running the query and puts the results in a comma separated list - However, when using the drop down all of the table tags were being displayed, so I thought that I need to query in place of the shortcode.

I think I am close, but missing something. If I use concat the drop down displays the number 1. If I use group_concat the drop down displays the number 15 (which is how many rows there are on the table).

```
    <?php
 

    add_action('quform_pre_display_7', function (Quform_Form $form) {
        $element = $form->getElement('quform_7_3');

    if ($element instanceof Quform_Element_Multi) {
        $options = array();
            global $wpdb;
            $results = $wpdb->query("SELECT CONCAT(Name) FROM `NAME_TABLE`"); 
            $results = array_map('trim', explode(',', $results));
        foreach ($results as $index => $option) {
            $options[] = array('label' => $option, 'value' => $option, 'id' => $index + 1);
        }

        $element->setOptions($options);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out all that was needed was to change it from "query" to "get_var" and it set the menu options.